# Cordova app crashes once then works fine (Windows Phone store)

Tags: cordova, windows-phone, windows-10-mobile, windows-phone-store

It has been a month since I have been unabled to update my Cordova app on Windows phone store. I always get a report saying that "the app opened then crashed directly".

On simulator and on real phone (debug mode), the app works fine. But I discovered, releasing a beta that when I download the app from the store on a windows 10 phone, first time I open it, the app close suddenly.

When I re-open it, everything is good and work correctly. I think that it's the reason why my app is always rejected.

Do you have any idea of what could happen here? How can I debug that ? :O

I'm desperate.

Thanks a lot,

Robin